# ActiveMQ High Availability dynamic slave configurations

Tags: dynamic, configuration, activemq-classic, high-availability, master-slave

I am quite new to ActiveMQ. I am trying to have High Availability feature implemented.
And all I noticed in ActiveMQ is that if I have to specify the failover url, I have to specify that in code like,

```
String url = "failover://(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:62001)?randomize=false";
ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
```

So it means that, If I have to add one more Slave, I need to go and change the URL here and redeploy the changes.
Or Either I need to have this URL in some property file.

Is there any other alternative configuration available to pick the dynamically added Slaves automatically

Thanks In advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using a network of brokers (instead of just master/slave), there is a  option called 'updateClusterClients' (new in 5.4) that does exactly this.  when set to "true" it automatically updates client failover lists based on availability of brokers in the network...

see http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html

Comment: tried above configurations looks to be its not working for me.
Below are few of my configurations
- Master activemq.xml
   `<transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616" updateClusterClients="true" updateClusterClientsOnRemove="true" 
    updateClusterFilter="*slave*" />
        </transportConnectors>`

Comment: - Slave configs

`<services><masterConnector remoteURI="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616" userName="" password=""/></services>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:62001"/>
        </transportConnectors>`

Comment: And URL `protected String url = "failover://(tcp://localhost:61616)?randomize=false";`

Comment: Failover URL I use is `failover:(tcp://h1,tcp://b2,...)?`, not `failover://(...)`